# which command can be used to determine if a file is binary

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I got some issues grepping a certain text in a folder.

```
grep "Notifying status" -R
Binary file fix2.log matches
```

It turns out that the file containing the text is *binary*. Actually it is a log file (created by PAC manager) and can be read properly using notepad++ (or any other text file). I'm not sure why the OS determines it a

When I do `ls` so all files are listed with the same `-rwxr--r--`

When I do `file fix2.log` it shows as `data`

Is there any command to show if a file is binary or not, example from `ls` view?

Comment: Why don't you just override `grep`'s determination and tell it to show you contents anyhow?

Comment: All files are binary; a text file is just one whose contents are assumed to be an encoding of text. What you show `ls` to be displaying are simply file permissions that are independent of the content of the file.

Comment: `ack` supports `-a` as well.

Comment: As Dustin shows below in his answer, the `file` command is *specifically* intended for this purpose.

Comment: thanks, when I do ` ack -a ...`, it says`Option '-a' is not valid in ack 2`

Comment: Indeed, 2.x changed their type handling rather wildly.

Comment: @artm Please accept an answer if either satisfied your query. We don't work for free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grep` is simply looking for non-ASCII content for its "binary" determination. You can trivially override this with the `-a` flag, to assume that all content is text:

```
grep -a "Notifying status" -R
```

Comment: This is true. But it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @viraptor, it addresses the OP's intent, rather than their question. Which is to say that I'm arguing that the OP asked the wrong question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy true you did answer my intention. The question was really an artifact. As I said I usually use `ack-grep` and I was misled by the fact that it omits the binary file.

Comment: `grep` seems very slow to me. But I'll need to work out how to get `ack-grep` to work with `-a` option in my system (Ubuntu).

Comment: *nod*. I'd suggest asking a question (perhaps on Unix SE or SuperUser) specifically about how to disable this detection in `ack` 2.x.

Answer (score 8):

Under Linux/Unix, look for anything that isn't "text/plain":

```
$ file -I -b /tmp/local-access.log
text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

Edit:

Actually, since `file` *does* classify between different types of text-file, the encoding might be the better way to go:

```
$ echo "Testing" | file -I -b -
text/plain; charset=us-ascii

$ echo "<html></html>" | file -I -b -
text/html; charset=us-ascii

$ echo "<?xml version="1.0"?><catalog></catalog>" | file -I -b -
application/xml; charset=us-ascii

$ echo "<?xml version="1.0"?><catalog></catalog>" | file --mime-encoding -b -
us-ascii
```

Note @CharlesDuffy's comment below. This will only check some head/tail information but, 1) this will be sufficient in all non-exotic situations (most binary files aren't going to have pure text at the front and back of the file), and 2) you don't necessarily want to check every byte if the input is of arbitrary length (e.g. 2G)

Comment: **Notice** the command that Dustin used here.  The `file` command, as used here, is *specifically intended* to identify the content of a file ... not just that "it is binary," but, "what it *is.*"  The `man file` page is very, very detailed as to precisely how the command works.

Comment: Notably, there's no guarantee that `file` and `grep` will make the same determination here -- `file` is typically only looking at the first and last 512 bytes, whereas `grep` necessarily needs to scan further into contents unless given an argument such as `-q` that lets it stop earlier (on first match, on first N matches, etc).

Comment: @MikeRobinson Not sure what you're trying to say. Since `file` looks for magic bytes and text-files don't have them, there will always just be the one result for any text file. So, they can just make sure it doesn't say "text/plain" and they'll be assured that it's binary.

Comment: @DustinOprea, eh? Text files can certainly have magic in the GNU-`file` sense. A shebang line? Magic. A byte order marker? Magic. etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's a great point, Charles. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: `text/*` should suffice for a decent number of cases. (`text/xml`, `text/x-shellscript`, `text/html`, etc).

Comment: Dustin, I am *agreeing with you," and trying to specifically call attention to the particular command that you used.

Comment: Unlike `file -I`, `grep` (both in the GNU and FreeBSD implementation, as of v2.22 and v2.51, respectively) regrettably classifies UTF-16-encoded text files as binary (both the LE and BE variants) - at least files that only contain characters in the code-point range 0 - 255 (which means that every other byte is a NUL byte).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Good point re `file -I` and `grep` determining binary status of a file differently; while any implementation must by default keep scanning a binary file until at least _1_ match is found, the _GNU_ implementation (v2.22) - smartly - stops scanning after the 1st match, whereas the FreeBSD v2.51 implementation (as found on OSX 10.11) needlessly keeps scanning (even though the match-found message only reflects _whether_ a (at least one) match was found).